# Going from a simple sockets application on local host to on the web

Tags: python, sockets, p2p

I want to learn how to write p2p applications. I have been playing around with sockets and have the most basic application like so `server.py`:

```
import socket
import sys

def main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"                   
    port = 5001
    mySocket = socket.socket()           
    mySocket.bind((host,port))
    mySocket.listen(1)                   
    print("Listening..")
    conn, addr = mySocket.accept()      
    print ("Connection from: " + str(addr))
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        if not data:                     
            break
        print ("From connected  user: " + str(addr))
        print ("Received from user: " + str(data))
        data = raw_input("Message: ")
        conn.send(data.encode())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and `client.py`:

```
import socket

def Main():
        host = '127.0.0.1'
        port = 5001
        mySocket = socket.socket()
        mySocket.connect((host,port))
        message = raw_input("Message: ")             # Need to send non unicode
        while message != 'q':                        # utf-8 binary code of unicode
                mySocket.send(message.encode())      # Encode utf-8 defualt
                data = mySocket.recv(1024).decode()  # Decode utf-8 default
                print ('Received from server: ' + data)
                message = raw_input("Message: ")
        mySocket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

This works great on localhost. My question is what would I have to do so this can be used on the web? E.g. I give my IP address someone not on the same network and they can connect. I want to be able to do this without the user having to forward ports in their router settings. How do apps like bittorent and bitcoin achieve this?

Comment: `How do apps like bittorent and bitcoin achieve this?` With [UPnP](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6970)

Comment: The user doesn't have to forward ports if they are running the client.  You as the server would have to forward ports if you are behind a NAT firewall.  Then you just have to give your external IP (google "whats my ip address").